# AngularJS - Passing function for child to run when entering text not being called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

I have a parent component (lot.changes) that passes a child component (lot.changes.list), a function to run when entering text into a text input (`ng-change="$ctrl.searchUpdated(true)"`). But the `searchUpdated` function never runs when entering text. Any idea why not?

**lot.changes.html**

```
<div layout="column" flex>
    <lot-changes-action-bar></lot-changes-action-bar>
    <div layout="row" flex>
        <div layout="column" flex="40">
            <lot-changes-list searchUpdated="$ctrl.searchUpdated" doSearch="$ctrl.doSearch" handleSearchError="$ctrl.handleSearchError" orderByChangeNumberDescending="$ctrl.orderByChangeNumberDescending" changeRecordClicked="$ctrl.changeRecordClicked" handleSearchResult="$ctrl.handleSearchResult"></lot-changes-list>
        </div>
        <div layout="row" flex="60">
            <!-- <lot-change-view selectedLotChange="$ctrl.selectedLotChange" layout="column" flex layout-margin></lot-change-view> -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**lot.changes.ts**

```
"use strict";

import { IEnumResource, ICbRoute } from "../../../core/core.module";

import { IDLotChangeLogic, /*IDLotChangeLogicItem, */ LogicFactory } from "../../../logic/logic.module";

class LotChangesController {
    static $inject = ["$location", "EnumResource", "CbRoute", "LogicFactory"];
    public query: string = "";
    public searchResults = [];
    private lotChangeLogic: IDLotChangeLogic;

    constructor(
        private $location: ng.ILocationService,
        public enumBase: IEnumResource,
        private cbRoute: ICbRoute,
        private logicFactory: LogicFactory
    ) {
        this.lotChangeLogic = logicFactory.getLotChangeLogic();
    }

    public searchUpdated(onNgChange: boolean): void {
        // if (onNgChange) {
        //     this.paramsChanged = true;
        // }
        // if (this.searchIsLoading || !this.paramsChanged) {
        //     return;
        // }
        this.searchResults = [];
        return this.doSearch();
    }

    doSearch = () => {
        // if (this.searchIsLoading || this.noMoreResults) {
        //     return;
        // }

        // this.currentPage ++;

        // let query = this.getSearchParams();
        // let extraParams = this.getExtraParams();
        // this.searchIsLoading = true;
        this.lotChangeLogic
            .getLotChangeItems(0)
            .$promise
            .then(this.handleSearchResult.bind(undefined, this.query))
            .catch(this.handleSearchError);
    };

    handleSearchError = () => {
        this.searchResults = [];
    }

    orderByChangeNumberDescending = (results: any) => {
        results.sort(function (a, b) {
            if (a.changeNumber > b.changeNumber) { return -1; }
            if (a.changeNumber < b.changeNumber) { return 1; }
            return 0;
        });
    }

    changeRecordClicked = (searchResultId: number) => {
        this.searchResults.forEach( result => {
            result.id === searchResultId ? result.isSelected = true : result.isSelected = false;
        });

        console.log(this.searchResults);
    }

    private handleSearchResult = (query: any, results: any): void => {
        //this.searchIsLoading = false;
        if ((!results) || results.length === 0) {
            //this.noMoreResults = true;
            console.log("no results");
        } else {
            this.orderByChangeNumberDescending(results);
            results.forEach(function(result) { result.isSelected = false; });
            console.log(results);
            this.searchResults.push.apply(this.searchResults, results);
            // this.$timeout(
            //     () => {
            //         this.$scope.$emit("list:filtered");
            //     },
            //     10);
        }

        // if (this.onSearch && query !== undefined) {
        //     this.onSearch();
        // }
    }
}

export class LotChangesComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    bindings: { [binding: string]: string; } = {
    };
    public templateUrl: string = "components/lots/changes/lot.changes.html";
    public controller: Function = LotChangesController;
}
```

**lot.changes.list.html**

```
<md-card layout="column" flex>
    <div layout="row" layout-margin>
        <div layout="row" layout-fill layout-align="start center">
            <md-icon>search</md-icon>
            <md-input-container md-no-float class="md-block" layout-fill>
                <!-- <input class="md-subhead" type="text" id="search-filter" name="search-filter" placeholder="Search" ng-model="$ctrl.query"
                    ng-change="$ctrl.searchUpdated(true)" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }"> -->

                <input placeholder="Type in Change Details" ng-model="$ctrl.query" on-search="$ctrl.searchUpdated(true)" ng-change="$ctrl.searchUpdated(true)" logic="$ctrl.lotLogic" class="md-subhead" type="text" id="search-filter" name="search-filter" ng-model="$ctrl.query"
                    ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }">
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </div>
    <md-divider></md-divider>


    <div layout="column" flex cb-fill-height>
        <div ng-repeat="searchResult in $ctrl.searchResults track by searchResult.id" ng-style="searchResult.isSelected && {'background-color':'rgba(68, 133, 243, 0.4)'}">
            <div layout="row" layout-align="start center" layout-margin style="padding: 8px; margin: 0;">
                <span layout-margin class="md-body-2">{{searchResult.changeNumber}}</span>
                <md-icon ng-if="searchResult.changeStatus === 0" class="md-warn">indeterminate_check_box</md-icon>
                <md-icon class="md-accent" ng-if="searchResult.changeStatus === 1">check_box_outline_blank</md-icon>
                <md-icon class="md-accent" ng-if="searchResult.changeStatus === 2">check_box_outline_blank</md-icon>
                <md-icon class="md-primary" ng-if="searchResult.changeStatus === 3">check_box</md-icon>
                <md-icon class="md-warn" ng-if="searchResult.changeStatus === 4">indeterminate_check_box</md-icon>
                <md-icon class="md-accent" ng-if="searchResult.changeStatus === 5">check_box_outline_blank</md-icon>
                <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column" flex>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
                    </p>
                </div>
                <md-button ng-disabled="searchResult.isSelected" class="md-icon-button md-raised" style="min-width: 40px" ng-click="$ctrl.changeRecordClicked(searchResult.id)">
                    <md-icon>exit_to_app</md-icon>
                </md-button>
            </div>
            <md-divider></md-divider>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-card>
```

**lot.changes.list.ts**

```
"use strict";

class LotChangesListController {
    searchUpdated;
    doSearch;
    handleSearchError; 
    orderByChangeNumberDescending; 
    changeRecordClicked;
    handleSearchResult;
}

export class LotChangesListComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    bindings: { [binding: string]: string; } = {
        logic: "<",
    };
    public templateUrl: string = "components/lots/changes/lot.changes.list.html";
    public controller: Function = LotChangesListController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding the attribute `searchUpdated` to your `log-changes-list` component, but from your `logs.changes.list.ts` it doesn't seem like you're defining the binding.

Try doing this

```
export class LotChangesListComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
    bindings: { [binding: string]: string; } = {
        logic: "<",
        searchUpdated: "&", // <-- add this binding
    };
    // ...
}
```

The correct way to use this binding would be

```
<log-changes-list search-updated="{PLACE_FN_HERE}"></log-changes-list>
```

Use it inside your component

```
this.searchUpdated();

// inside your template 
$ctrl.searchUpdate(/* params */);
```

Hopefully this helps.